# Oracle SQL Developer table options in tree view

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When right clicking a table in the tree view the options are ordered first Edit and second Open instead of Open being the first option.
I had this problem several years ago but can´t remember the solution.
Anyone knows how to switch the order of the options so i can auto open the table tabs?
Thank you.

Comment: Just double click to open the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that to be the intended behavior -

[image]

You can configure SQL Developer to open an object by either clicking on it, the default behavior, or double-clicking on it.

That's controlled by this (I prefer double-clicks, it's more intentional, and allows for multi-select, drag and drop)

[image]

The context menu by mouse is also available of course.

Comment: When i booted my desktop and restarted SQL Developer, the intended behavior worked again. I know it is a basic procedure but because the desktop computer was coming from a fresh boot i never suspected it would need another. As i was tinkering with some options i thought it could be something else. Thanks.